# Page.Validate() in ASP.net WebForms to run within a div?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am developing a mobile site which has multiple divs. I have validator set up for each different input, but I want to validate only the elements within the 1st div on click "Continue."

In the example, I want to validate First name only within FirstPage.

SecondPage is hidden until continue_click event.

```
<div id="FirstPage" runat="server">

<h3>*First Name:</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name."
    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="Continue" runat="server" Text="Next" 
        onclick="Continue_Click" />
</div>

<div id="SecondPage" runat="server">

    <h3>*Last Name:</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastNameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="LastName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your last name."
    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Validation Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx), which will allow you to well... group validation :)

You need to add the `validationgroup` attribute to your `RequiredFieldValidator` and your `Button`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name."
    ForeColor="Red"
    ValidationGroup="FirstPage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Continue" runat="server" Text="Next" 
        onclick="Continue_Click"
        ValidationGroup="FirstPage" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I went to the link and was able to get the answer.

Comment: The button needs CausesValidation="true" though.

Comment: @tpae - CausesValidation defaults to `true` for the `Button` control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the ValidationGroup property on your RequiredFieldValidator like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name."
    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="first"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Then your button would refer to that group:

```
<asp:Button ID="Continue" runat="server" Text="Next" ValidationGroup="first" onclick="Continue_Click" />
```